# In enumerate, how to continue number sequence into sublist?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I need to make a list with sublists, where the sublists have indentation but continue the same numbered sequence. Like this:

1. one
2. two
   3. third, sublist of two
   4. continuing sequence, grouped with third
3. five (the markdown here keeps changing the number to 3, but it should be 5)

Of course there are ways to hack it, e.g. by adding indentation to a simple enumerate,
but I'm more interested in whether there is a more elegant solution.
Particularly, one which both **groups sublists** to have matching indentation, and **auto-numbers** all the items, seems it should be possible.

The [enumitem package](https://nhigham.com/2019/12/17/lists-in-latex-with-the-enumitem-package/) is said to be highly flexible -- perhaps there is a way to do this somewhat elegantly with that package? I am starting to look through the documentation there, but does anyone know how or whether this can be done, or whether I am looking in the right place at enumitem?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a solution in "which both groups sublists ... have matching indentation".

Comment: @Mico thanks for the response! All I meant by 'groups sublists to have matching indentation', was instead of marking indentation line-by-line, sublists of lines with matching indentation are marked as a group. For example, how this is typically done with sequences restarting in sublists; the group starts with `\begin{enumerate}` and ends with `\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: Thanks. So, in your opinion, does the answer I provided meet your objective?

Comment: @Mico yes, it looks awesome. I am still trying to understand just how it works, but I can tell that it meets both those requirements mentioned, and I plan to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs the `enumitem` package to carry over the numbering of items in first-level `enumerate` environments to the second-level `enumerate` environments.

[image]

Aside: I must confess that I didn't understand what you meant by wanting to have "both groups sublists ... have matching indentation". Should they have the *same* indentation, maybe? If level-1 and level-2 enumerated items are supposed to share the same counter and the same exterior appearance, that would be indistinguishable from having a *single* (level-1, presumably?) enumerated environment, no? Please clarify.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\protect\refstepcounter{enumi}%
                            \protect\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}%
                            \arabic{enumii}.,
                      ref=\arabic{enumii}
                     }
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A \label{item:a}
\item B 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item B.a 
  \item B.b \label{item:bb}
  \end{enumerate}
\item C \label{item:c}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Items \ref{item:a}, \ref{item:bb}, and \ref{item:c}.
\end{document}
```